# failed to deploy a node js app to heroku from cloud 9

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

its a small application i followed all the instructions including adding the `start script` but i keep getting this error from the heroku

Here's the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "marv",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A profolio page",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "mike",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.5.5",
    "express": "^4.14.1"
  }
}
```

This is the error -

```
2017-01-31T05:11:14.825901+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:11:14.825901+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:11:14.989987+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:11:14.989987+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:20:36.077445+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-01-31T05:20:36.077451+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-01-31T05:20:35.734320+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:20:35.718069+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:20:35.718069+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7f1c52d by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:20:37.566305+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-01-31T05:20:41.088789+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:41.088803+00:00 app[web.1]: > marv@1.0.0 start /app
2017-01-31T05:20:41.088804+00:00 app[web.1]: > start
2017-01-31T05:20:41.088805+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:41.097045+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: start: not found
2017-01-31T05:20:41.103526+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:41.116072+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2017-01-31T05:20:41.116428+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-01-31T05:20:41.116677+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2017-01-31T05:20:41.116934+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2017-01-31T05:20:41.117178+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-01-31T05:20:41.117442+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-01-31T05:20:41.117721+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-01-31T05:20:41.117993+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-01-31T05:20:41.118222+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! marv@1.0.0 start: `start`
2017-01-31T05:20:41.118415+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-01-31T05:20:41.118630+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-01-31T05:20:41.118873+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the marv@1.0.0 start script 'start'.
2017-01-31T05:20:41.119049+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-01-31T05:20:41.119467+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the marv package,
2017-01-31T05:20:41.120001+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     start
2017-01-31T05:20:41.119638+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-01-31T05:20:41.119822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-01-31T05:20:41.120216+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-01-31T05:20:41.120424+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs marv
2017-01-31T05:20:41.120617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-01-31T05:20:41.120818+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls marv
2017-01-31T05:20:41.121035+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-01-31T05:20:41.129120+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:41.129459+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-01-31T05:20:41.129610+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-01-31T05:20:41.223482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-01-31T05:20:41.224934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-01-31T05:20:41.210116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-01-31T05:20:42.469734+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-01-31T05:20:44.883393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-01-31T05:20:44.806999+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:44.807014+00:00 app[web.1]: > marv@1.0.0 start /app
2017-01-31T05:20:44.807016+00:00 app[web.1]: > start
2017-01-31T05:20:44.817065+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:44.807016+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:44.812651+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: start: not found
2017-01-31T05:20:44.824762+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2017-01-31T05:20:44.824962+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825083+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825202+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825325+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825437+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825560+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825670+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825786+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! marv@1.0.0 start: `start`
2017-01-31T05:20:44.825959+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826051+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the marv@1.0.0 start script 'start'.
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826132+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826213+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the marv package,
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826297+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826497+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826593+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     start
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826700+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826781+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs marv
2017-01-31T05:20:44.826931+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls marv
2017-01-31T05:20:44.827008+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-01-31T05:20:44.830167+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:20:44.830314+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-01-31T05:20:44.830375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-01-31T05:20:44.899323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-01-31T05:21:38.894783+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-01-31T05:21:38.894788+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-01-31T05:21:38.799955+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:21:38.799955+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7d18209 by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:21:39.897641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-01-31T05:21:41.074961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-01-31T05:21:43.515136+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:21:43.515151+00:00 app[web.1]: > marv@1.0.0 start /app
2017-01-31T05:21:43.515152+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-01-31T05:21:43.515153+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:21:43.697680+00:00 app[web.1]: The Server is started!!!
2017-01-31T05:21:44.743866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

AFTER ADDING THE PROCFILE I GET THIS HEROKU LOGS

```
2017-01-31T05:26:08.229183+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls marv
2017-01-31T05:26:08.229058+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.229348+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.290511+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:26:08.290781+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.290916+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-01-31T05:26:08.475246+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:26:08.545154+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2017-01-31T05:26:08.545500+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-01-31T05:26:08.546159+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2017-01-31T05:26:08.546417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2017-01-31T05:26:08.546666+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-01-31T05:26:08.546882+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! marv@1.0.0 start: `npm start`
2017-01-31T05:26:08.547076+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-01-31T05:26:08.549104+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-01-31T05:26:08.549297+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the marv@1.0.0 start script 'npm start'.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.549462+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.549604+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the marv package,
2017-01-31T05:26:08.549790+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.549969+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.550147+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm start
2017-01-31T05:26:08.550318+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.550487+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs marv
2017-01-31T05:26:08.550681+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.550872+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls marv
2017-01-31T05:26:08.551060+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.617254+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:26:08.617509+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.618004+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-01-31T05:26:08.830443+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:26:08.892539+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2017-01-31T05:26:08.893654+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2017-01-31T05:26:08.892769+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-01-31T05:26:08.893455+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2017-01-31T05:26:08.894315+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.893808+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-01-31T05:26:08.894418+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the marv package,
2017-01-31T05:26:08.893949+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! marv@1.0.0 start: `npm start`
2017-01-31T05:26:08.894066+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-01-31T05:26:08.895201+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm start
2017-01-31T05:26:08.894251+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-01-31T05:26:08.894256+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the marv@1.0.0 start script 'npm start'.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.894521+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.894990+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.895202+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.952788+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:26:08.953066+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.895282+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs marv
2017-01-31T05:26:08.897067+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-01-31T05:26:08.897178+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls marv
2017-01-31T05:26:08.897280+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-01-31T05:26:08.953178+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-01-31T05:26:09.150119+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:26:09.217843+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2017-01-31T05:26:09.218096+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2017-01-31T05:26:09.218486+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2017-01-31T05:26:09.218813+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! marv@1.0.0 start: `npm start`
2017-01-31T05:26:09.218310+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2017-01-31T05:26:09.219095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-01-31T05:26:09.219227+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the marv@1.0.0 start script 'npm start'.
2017-01-31T05:26:09.219367+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2017-01-31T05:26:09.219511+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the marv package,
2017-01-31T05:26:09.218971+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2017-01-31T05:26:09.218661+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-01-31T05:26:09.219614+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2017-01-31T05:26:09.220306+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm start
2017-01-31T05:26:09.221240+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs marv
2017-01-31T05:26:09.219752+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2017-01-31T05:26:09.223347+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls marv
2017-01-31T05:26:09.223736+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-01-31T05:26:09.290178+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:26:09.290435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2017-01-31T05:26:09.221908+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2017-01-31T05:26:09.220453+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2017-01-31T05:26:09.290544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-01-31T05:26:09.404748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-01-31T05:26:09.443702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-01-31T05:35:34.314557+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-01-31T05:35:34.314566+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-01-31T05:35:34.176941+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:35:34.176941+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 824747a by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T05:35:34.977944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-01-31T05:35:36.147096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-01-31T05:35:38.722345+00:00 app[web.1]: > marv@1.0.0 start /app
2017-01-31T05:35:38.722346+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-01-31T05:35:38.722347+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:35:38.722331+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-31T05:35:38.920123+00:00 app[web.1]: The Server is started!!!
2017-01-31T05:35:39.924169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-31T06:10:46.642422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-01-31T06:10:46.643066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-01-31T06:10:47.333913+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-31T06:10:47.511409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-01-31T06:48:20.922256+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-01-31T06:48:20.922263+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-01-31T06:48:20.740607+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T06:48:20.740607+00:00 app[api]: Deploy b5ee661 by user youraveragecoder@gmail.com
2017-01-31T06:48:21.077507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-01-31T06:48:22.779283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2017-01-31T06:48:25.506272+00:00 app[web.1]: The Server is started!!!
2017-01-31T06:48:26.473056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: It seems heroku is unable to find the right file to start your server. Can you post your package.json and through which file do you start your server. Make sure that the **start** script in you package.json has the correct command to start your server.

Comment: let me post my package.json file for you

Comment: Is your app working fine locally? If yes then how do you run it locally? I mean by which command do you run it locally.

Comment: it runs locally i used node app.js to run the app,its a simple 2 page html skeleton trying to create a pro folio page but first am attempting to deploy it first just to be sure,i've searched and i just cant understand that error

Comment: Its should work then. Make sure your heroku server has this package.json with the start command. As another alternative - Follow this - Make a file in the root directory of your project with the name **Procfile** and add into the file this line - `web: node app.js`. Push the app to Heroku again. After this, Heroku will try to run the app using the Procfile.

Comment: I went back created the file **Procfile** then commited it to Git then pushed it to heroku and it still doesnt work and maybe i forgot to mention this it keeps redirecting me to the Deploying page so am assuming am still doing something wrong,anyway thank you for the tips i'll keep looking for the problem

Comment: Try posting the log again after adding the Procfile.

Comment: i've already posted it